# MomentJS with tampermonkey errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I'm playing about with tamper monkey and im trying to change dates to moment from-now format and I keep getting errors trying to require it or importing the script into a website.

Here is basic form of the script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         TL momentjs
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  add moment js to tl!
// @author       You
// @match        http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/
// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */

'use strict';

// Your code here...
$('.forumindex:nth-child(3n+4)').each(function(function() {
    datestr = $(this)[0].innerText.split(",")[0];
    user = $(this)[0].innerText.split(",")[1];
    console.log( $(this)[0].innerText = moment(datestr).fromNow() + ", " + user);
});
```

The errors im getting are

```
Syntax error @ 'TL momentjs'!
##########################
JSHINT output:
require: (W030) Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression on line: 11 at character: 29
require: (W033) Missing semicolon on line: 11 at character: 30
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 85 at character: 19
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 92 at character: 24
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 115 at character: 19
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 185 at character: 38
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 196 at character: 46
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 196 at character: 78
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 384 at character: 23
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 411 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 415 at character: 28
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 416 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 419 at character: 16
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 597 at character: 19
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 652 at character: 19
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 664 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 664 at character: 40
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 665 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 670 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 670 at character: 45
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 671 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 677 at character: 14
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 678 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 679 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 680 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 686 at character: 28
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 687 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 687 at character: 61
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 688 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 688 at character: 62
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 690 at character: 29
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 691 at character: 31
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 691 at character: 61
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 692 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 695 at character: 48
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 697 at character: 54
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 699 at character: 35
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 730 at character: 19
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 731 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 732 at character: 45
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 733 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 735 at character: 33
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 740 at character: 28
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 740 at character: 41
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 745 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 746 at character: 29
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 747 at character: 41
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 750 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 752 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 755 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 756 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 756 at character: 48
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 762 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 763 at character: 29
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 764 at character: 41
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 767 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 769 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 772 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 773 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 773 at character: 43
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 787 at character: 30
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 788 at character: 29
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 789 at character: 30
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 790 at character: 30
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 803 at character: 9
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 804 at character: 9
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 804 at character: 34
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 805 at character: 9
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 806 at character: 9
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 923 at character: 28
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 935 at character: 32
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 940 at character: 42
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1066 at character: 27
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1133 at character: 15
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1136 at character: 15
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 1165 at character: 42
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 1165 at character: 70
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 1187 at character: 43
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 1193 at character: 53
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1208 at character: 25
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1221 at character: 18
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1221 at character: 33
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1221 at character: 48
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1242 at character: 21
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1248 at character: 28
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1261 at character: 36
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 1343 at character: 22
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1347 at character: 33
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1349 at character: 32
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1383 at character: 32
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 1401 at character: 29
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1697 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1699 at character: 14
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1700 at character: 26
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1700 at character: 36
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1702 at character: 19
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1708 at character: 18
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1709 at character: 45
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1711 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1712 at character: 13
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1713 at character: 29
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1714 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1717 at character: 39
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1718 at character: 47
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1719 at character: 29
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1720 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1721 at character: 53
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1722 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1725 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1727 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1727 at character: 57
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 1732 at character: 19
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1737 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1739 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1741 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1746 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1750 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1751 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1752 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1755 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1755 at character: 45
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1758 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1762 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1763 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1763 at character: 28
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1764 at character: 27
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1765 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1765 at character: 58
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1767 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1771 at character: 14
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1776 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1781 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1781 at character: 32
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1782 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1782 at character: 32
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1787 at character: 26
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1788 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1793 at character: 23
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1798 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1798 at character: 34
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1801 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1804 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1808 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1808 at character: 34
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1812 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1812 at character: 33
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1816 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1816 at character: 33
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1816 at character: 48
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 1868 at character: 29
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 1957 at character: 37
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1980 at character: 40
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1981 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1991 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1991 at character: 38
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1991 at character: 73
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 1995 at character: 27
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2000 at character: 15
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2005 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2007 at character: 35
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2013 at character: 15
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2018 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2020 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2025 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2025 at character: 45
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2031 at character: 15
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2036 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2039 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2039 at character: 78
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2044 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2044 at character: 45
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2048 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2048 at character: 45
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2056 at character: 14
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2060 at character: 39
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2066 at character: 41
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2071 at character: 32
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2078 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2112 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2116 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2120 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2130 at character: 35
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2131 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2135 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2138 at character: 48
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2138 at character: 74
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2140 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2145 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2149 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2152 at character: 50
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2152 at character: 74
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2154 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2159 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2169 at character: 20
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 2172 at character: 31
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2173 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2175 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2191 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2200 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2204 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2209 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2240 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2242 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2246 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2246 at character: 29
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2250 at character: 28
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2254 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2254 at character: 41
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2254 at character: 49
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2258 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2263 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2277 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2277 at character: 33
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2281 at character: 31
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2285 at character: 43
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2289 at character: 32
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2294 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2295 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2296 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2297 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2298 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2348 at character: 42
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2350 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2351 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2352 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2353 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2357 at character: 42
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2358 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2358 at character: 40
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2362 at character: 28
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2366 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2367 at character: 28
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 2372 at character: 19
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2373 at character: 31
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2379 at character: 36
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2388 at character: 9
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2389 at character: 9
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2390 at character: 9
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2391 at character: 16
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 2412 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2412 at character: 43
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2412 at character: 68
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2412 at character: 97
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2441 at character: 32
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2441 at character: 48
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2450 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2454 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2460 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2460 at character: 43
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 2461 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2461 at character: 39
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2465 at character: 31
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 2466 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2466 at character: 39
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 2531 at character: 21
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2565 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2565 at character: 42
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2566 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2566 at character: 28
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2571 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2576 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2582 at character: 14
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2583 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2584 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2585 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2586 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2593 at character: 28
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2594 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2594 at character: 63
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2595 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2595 at character: 64
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2596 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2596 at character: 62
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2598 at character: 18
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2599 at character: 31
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2599 at character: 63
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2599 at character: 100
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2600 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2603 at character: 48
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2605 at character: 54
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2607 at character: 53
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2609 at character: 35
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2618 at character: 14
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 2619 at character: 26
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2619 at character: 36
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2621 at character: 19
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2621 at character: 33
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2621 at character: 55
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 2622 at character: 19
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2623 at character: 41
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2624 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2631 at character: 14
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 2632 at character: 26
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2632 at character: 36
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2634 at character: 24
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2634 at character: 41
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 2635 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2635 at character: 42
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2639 at character: 14
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 2640 at character: 26
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2640 at character: 36
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 2645 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2645 at character: 32
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2645 at character: 50
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2645 at character: 59
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2669 at character: 37
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2669 at character: 67
require: (W041) Use '===' to compare with 'null' on line: 2670 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2670 at character: 44
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2676 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2894 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 2898 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3024 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3038 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3039 at character: 27
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3045 at character: 9
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3049 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3055 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3062 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3086 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3093 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3102 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3104 at character: 17
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3109 at character: 9
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3109 at character: 48
require: (W041) Use '!==' to compare with 'null' on line: 3175 at character: 19
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3226 at character: 30
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3228 at character: 9
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3341 at character: 20
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3341 at character: 57
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3358 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3359 at character: 13
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3360 at character: 14
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3361 at character: 19
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3382 at character: 16
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3400 at character: 25
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3456 at character: 22
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3457 at character: 54
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3460 at character: 41
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3476 at character: 39
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3477 at character: 44
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3478 at character: 44
require: (W040) Possible strict violation on line: 3499 at character: 21
script: (W030) Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression on line: 13 at character: 1
script: (W024) Expected an identifier and instead saw 'function' (a reserved word) on line: 16 at character: 48
script: (E020) Expected ')' to match '(' from line 3623 and instead saw '(' on line: 16 at character: 56
script: (W118) 'function closure expressions' is only available in Mozilla JavaScript extensions (use moz option) on line: 16 at character: 56
script: (E030) Expected an identifier and instead saw ')' on line: 16 at character: 57
script: (W116) Expected ')' and instead saw '{' on line: 16 at character: 59
script: (W033) Missing semicolon on line: 16 at character: 60
script: (E041) Unrecoverable syntax error. (99% scanned) on line: 19 at character: 1
##########################

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Function (native)
    at c (<anonymous>:41:115)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:1:24)
    at eval (native)
    at n (<anonymous>:72:175)
    at ja (<anonymous>:41:158)
    at ma (<anonymous>:83:93)
    at b (<anonymous>:83:318)
```

Also I've tried couple of things like document.createElement('script') and tried google but I am unable to figure this out.

Comment: This needs an answer from someone who knows how TamperMonkey loads modules.  Feel free to keep it here, but you may get a better response at https://forum.tampermonkey.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a superflous **function(** statement at your code. So you have to make your code look like this:

```
// Your code here...
$('.forumindex:nth-child(3n+4)').each(function() {
    datestr = $(this)[0].innerText.split(",")[0];
    user = $(this)[0].innerText.split(",")[1];
    console.log( $(this)[0].innerText = moment(datestr).fromNow() + "," + user);
});
```

Since user scripts are evaluated by Tampermonkey it's not possible to determine line numbers from the thrown errors. That's why Tampermonkey tries to find the syntax via a JSHint check.

Tip: manually starting the syntax check at the editor will find the error as well.